# excel vba macro: copy and paste the specific column to another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

i am new in macro and VBA coding.

I have two workbooks. one is report.xls, another one is AT.xlsm.

In report.xls, there has the sheet called "Service".

In AT.xlsm, there has the sheet called "Worksheet".

I want to auto copy the column B,C,F,J,E,D expect first row of report to the column A,C,D,E,F,H of AT.
So, i try to record a macro and revise the code, it can copy and paste but it saved to same location.

Would you please tell me how to paste to new row?

Thank you very much.

Code:

```
Sub Module1()
'Hot key: Ctrl+Shift+G

Windows("report.xls").Activate
Range("B2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("AT.xlsm").Activate
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("report.xls").Activate
Range("C2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("AT.xlsm").Activate
Range("C5380").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("report.xls").Activate
Range("F2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("AT.xlsm").Activate
Range("D5380").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("report.xls").Activate
Range("J2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("AT.xlsm").Activate
Range("E5380").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("report.xls").Activate
Range("E2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("AT.xlsm").Activate
Range("F5380").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("report.xls").Activate
Range("D2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("AT.xlsm").Activate
Range("H5380").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("report.xls").Activate
Range("G2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("AT.xlsm").Activate
Range("J5380").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("F5380").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Replace What:="[S]", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
ReplaceFormat:=False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be activating and selecting anything to copy over to another worksheet.  wss and wsw are explicit references to your worksheets.

```
Sub Tester546()
Set wb = Workbook("report.xls")
Set wb2 = Workbook("AT.xlsm")
Set wss = wb.Sheets("Service")
Set wsw = wb.Sheets("Worksheet")
wss.Range(wss.Cells(2, 2), wss.Cells(wss.Range("B" & wss.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row, 2)).Copy wsw.Cells(1, 1)
wss.Range(wss.Cells(2, 3), wss.Cells(wss.Range("C" & wss.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row, 3)).Copy wsw.Cells(5380, 3)
wss.Range(wss.Cells(2, 6), wss.Cells(wss.Range("F" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row, 6)).Copy wsw.Cells(5380, 4)
wss.Range(wss.Cells(2, 10), wss.Cells(wss.Range("J" & wss.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row, 10)).Copy wsw.Cells(5380, 5)
wss.Range(wss.Cells(2, 5), wss.Cells(wss.Range("E" & wss.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row, 5)).Copy wsw.Cells(5380, 6)
wss.Range(wss.Cells(2, 4), wss.Cells(wss.Range("D" & wss.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row, 4)).Copy wsw.Cells(5380, 8)
wsw.Range(wsw.Cells(5380, 6), wsw.Cells(wsw.Range("F" & wsw.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row, 6)).Replace What:="[S]", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

End Sub
```

You should be able to replace the 5380 on the destination worksheet (wsw) with

```
wsW.Range("D" & wss.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row +1
```

Changing the Column (here it's "D", to the columns you need.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, may I know that how to change the cells(5380) to the cells in any row of column A?

Comment: I don't always want cell 5380. I want to paste my data then go to last row + 1.  the cell would change with each copy and paste,  what i need to change in the code?  Thanks

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

I will use a portion of your code.
VBA code made while you record a macro is not the best option to use, but this time I will use the code in order to don't do things complicated to you.

Original code:

```
Windows("report.xls").Activate
Range("B2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("AT.xlsm").Activate
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Modify like:

```
Windows("report.xls").Activate    'This activate the report
Range("B2").Select    'This selects B2 cell
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select    'This expands the selection down
Selection.Copy    'This copy the selection.
Windows("AT.xlsm").Activate    'This activate the AT file
Range("B2").Select    '**** Here you should modify to select the Paste destination cell
ActiveSheet.Paste    'This Paste the values
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and add the comment that make me easier to understand.